# App closes without any prompt on clicking the button

Tags: java, android

when i click on the "ChangeBudgetBtn" the next activity i.e. BudgetEdit does not open and the application closes without any prompt

```
package com.moneymgmt.moneymanagementsystem;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class BudgetFragment extends Fragment {

Button ChangeBudgetBtn;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_budget, container,false);

        ChangeBudgetBtn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ChangeBudgetBtn);

        ChangeBudgetBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(),BudgetEdit.class));
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
}
```

Comment: Post your logcat please.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line

> `final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_budget, false);`

by the following line

```
final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_budget, container, false);
```

because you forgot to add the container parameter

Comment: ohhh...thanks i made the changes ....but the code has still same response..the app is still closing

Comment: post your logcat and make sure of the button id whether it is right or not and one more thing from fragment you can not start another activity, but you can user 
context.startActivity(......)

we do this in Kotlin just try it may it helps

Comment: Oh yes, what is that v.getContext() replace it with BudgetFragment.super.getContext()